# How to define pgfmath local variables?

Tags: pgfmath

When using `pfgmathsetmacro` in commands (defined by `\newcommand`) we have a problem of locality of variables. For instance if you design two functions

```
\newcommand\f[4]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#3{cosh(#1+#2)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#4{cos(#1+#2)}%
}
\newcommand\g[4]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#3{sqrt(1+(#1-#2)^2)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#4{sqrt((#1)^2+(#2)^2)}%
}
```

and want to define the composed function

```
\newcommand\h[4]{%
  \f#1#2\x\y%
  \g\x\y#3#4%
}
```

How do you protect the variables `\x` and `\y` such that you do not have to worry about not naming other variables `\x` or `\y` ?
If you have only one variable, the problem can be avoided using `\pgfmathresult`, but what if you have two (or more !) variables ?

Comment: Using \begingroup \endgroup pushes the contents of all registers onto the stack, then restores them when done.  In other words, what happens in a scope stays in a scope (unless you use \global}.

Comment: OTOH, why are you using \pgfsetmacro instead of just executing the commands with the given arguments?  You still need to save \pgfmathresult after each.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo. Thank you for this idea about `\begingroup`/`endgroup` !

Comment: @JohnKormylo. There is still something that escapes about your answer: if you define `\newcommand\h[4]{\begingroup\f#1#2\x\y \g\x\y#3#4 \endgroup}` how is the content of `\h{1}{2}\x\y` retrieved ? Why isn't it lost after `\endgroup` ?

Comment: You need to add \gloabl\edef#1{#1} etc.  It might be easier just to use really obscure names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll show a simplified version with one variable functions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\funcF[2]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{cosh(#2)}%
}
\newcommand\funcG[2]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sqrt(#2)}%
}

\newcommand{\compose}[4]{%
  \begingroup
  #3\x{#4}%
  #2\x{\x}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\pgfmathsetmacro\noexpand#1{\x}}\x
}

\newcommand{\funcH}[2]{%
  \compose#1\funcG\funcF{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\funcH\firstvalue{1}$\firstvalue$

\funcH\secondvalue{2}$\secondvalue$

\end{document}
```

The “local variable” `\x` is forgotten as soon as the final `\x` is executed.

[image]

Instead of `\x` you might want to use `\AcOmMaNdNaMeThAtSpRoBaBlYnOtUsEd` or something unusual like this.

Here's the response from `bc -l`, that shows that the functions are computed correctly, given the low precision with PGF:

```
> bc -l
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
sqrt((e(1)+e(-1))/2)
1.24220796761864467541
sqrt((e(2)+e(-2))/2)
1.93963803094382315206
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\h}[2]{%
\begingroup%
\edef\x{#1}
\global\edef#2{#1}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\def\x{0}
\def\y{1}

\h{2}{\y}

x=\x\newline
y=\y\newline

\end{document}
```

If you remove the \begingroup \endgroup, you will get x=2, y=2.  If you remove the \global you will get x=0, y=1.  (I don't know if \pgfmathsetmacro uses \global or not, but I would guess not.)